# Wget Minimum Download Rate

Tags: wget

Can anyone help with the parameter that ensures that wget will fetch the file at a minimum specified  download rate?

Comment: This doesn't seem theoretically possible.  If I have a 1Mb connection and I set the minimum to 10Mb/s, how is `wget` going to achieve that?  Did you mean "maximum" instead of "minimum"?

Answer (score 4):

You can not set minimum download rate. You can set the maximum download rate using `--limit-rate=amount` option. Amount is expressed in bytes per second.